# Canvas incorrectly antialiasing. Is there a way to force correct rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am having a problem rendering to the canvas with `ctx.imageSmoothingEnabled = true` When it mixes the colours it makes them too dark. The colour should be square root of the mean of the sum of the squared input values. What I get is the mean of the sum of the inputs.

Pixels colours values represent the square root of the actual photons emitted on the screen or captured via a camera. The antialiasing on all the machines I have looked at seem to do it incorrectly and this results in annoying dark artifacts around the high contrast parts of the image.

The code showing the correct and incorrect way to get an average RGB value for a 2 by 2 pixel area.

```
// 2 by 2 pixel down to 1 pixel
// the correct way
var r = Math.sqrt( (r11*r11 + r12*r12 + r21*r21 + r22*r22) / 4);
var g = Math.sqrt( (g11*g11 + g12*g12 + g21*g21 + g22*g22) / 4);
var b = Math.sqrt( (b11*b11 + b12*b12 + b21*b21 + b22*b22) / 4);

// how canvas render does it ?? (I am assuming)
var r = (r11 + r12 + r21 + r22) / 4;
var g = (g11 + g12 + g21 + g22) / 4;
var b = (b11 + b12 + b21 + b22) / 4;
```

What i would like to know is. Is there a way around this, via a browser setting (any browser I am desperate), hardware device setting, or any other technique?

Currently I am forced to render the canvas image in software which is excruciatingly slow in JavaScript especially when rendering out .WEBM and .GIF formats. Surely others must have encountered this and solved the problem as it almost makes using canvas "2D" pointless.

I have an image that shows the problem but not sure how to upload it here for display.

Comment: According to the [specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/scripting.html#dom-context-2d-drawimage) Note on point 4 : "This specification does not define the precise algorithm to use when scaling an image down, or when scaling an image up when the imageSmoothingEnabled attribute is set to true." So it's up to the browser to use any algorithm he likes. But the one you described looks like the `nearest-neighbor interpolation`, which is returned when setting `imageSmoothingEnabled = false`

Comment: @Kaiido Thanks. I use `imageSmoothingEnabled = false`  setting and I render via GPU at twice or four times the resolution (depending on my own quality settings) and then use first algorithm to create the correct antialiasing for the output. For HD this is very slow due to the software re-render,

Comment: But if you do re-render with software, why don't you do it directly from the original image? Ps, do you use [Uint32Array Tip](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/12/faster-canvas-pixel-manipulation-with-typed-arrays/) to boost the pixel manipulation?

Comment: @Kaiido The rendering is a composite of many images, video, SVG, and canvas 2d context vector drawing and uses many of the different `ctx.globalCompositeOperation`  (BTW the SVG and Canvas vector both have incorrect antialiasing.). Each frame is passed to a webworker and I do use `Uint8ClampedArray` to manipulate the data (shifting the channels out and then back into the 32bit format is slower than using the 8bit array.)

Comment: There is no vector drawing in canvas, just pixels.  The antialiasing is made in the `drawImage` method, which algorithm is dependent of the browser's choice. The svg element does have a [`shape-rendering`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Attribute/shape-rendering) attribute, that the `drawImage` will try to honor, but not as good as the CSS renderer. Then, since you're doing less operations on the array, I think that 32bits or 8bitClampedArray are still faster than operations on Uint8Array

Comment: @Kaiido Are not all the rendering functions that are completed with the `ctx.fill` and `ctx.stroke` methods vector rendering onto the canvas. I store them all specifically because they are resolution independent and render them for each frame. I do not know how to turn the anti aliasing off on these. The SVG comes in as is, just as any image element. I do not mess with it until it is rendered on the canvas.

Comment: `fill` and `stroke` will draw pixels, based on the vector defined in the path you gave, but still, it's pixels. They're not resolution independent, they're based on the context matrix. You can't disable the antialiasing of these methods (except from drawing at a bigger scale on another canvas and then drawing this other canvas to the main one). If you don't set `shape-rendering` on the svg, then the default `auto`, which a mix of performance and quality, is applied.

Comment: Guess its is a matter of semantics. If I create a font size 12px and use `ctx.fillText()` to render it, setting the matrix to [2,0,0,2,0,0] does not keep the 12px size but renders the text as 24px, same applies to all the rendering of canvas vectors, they are resolution independent until after they are transformed and clipped. Its just that the canvas does not store them, they are store in code. I render 60 times per second (or as close to that as possible) I treat them as vectors.

Comment: Its not the same as the font has increased its resolution by 4 while a bitmap would not have, it has only got bigger. All graphics on browsers is ultimately rendered as a bitmap. It is the abstraction we call vectors, these are rendered to a bitmap. I store all the fills and strokes as points, they are resolution independent. I rerender them every frame. This is the same thing SVG does, just that the individual render calls are hidden on SVG but the output is always bitmaps for the browser display.